# qemu-system-aarch64 - 'virtio-vga-gl' is not a valid device model name

Tags: qemu

I configured and built qemu 6.2.0 with --enable-sdl --enable-opengl --enable-virglrenderer parameters as qemu-system-aarch64 target for an amd64 ubuntu host. When I try to enable -device virtio-vga-gl is tells me that it is not a valid device model name.

Did I miss something?

Regards.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, May I know if have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the virtio-vga device is not compiled in by default for aarch64, because the intention is that it's only for machine types where there is legacy firmware that does not know about virtio-gpu but only about VGA (such as the x86 PC machine types). The recommended graphics type for the aarch64 'virt' board (according to [the documentation](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/arm/virt.html)) is `virtio-gpu-pci`. Your guest OS will obviously need support for that device type.

Comment: Okay, it does accept virtio-gpu-pci. Will this be enough for hardware accelerated Opengl?

Comment: Apparently not. dmesg says "virgl 3d acceleration not supported by host"

Comment: -device virtio-gpu-pci,virgl=true yields Property 'virtio-gpu-pci.virgl' not found.

Comment: That works on qemu 6.1 & older only, on 6.2+ it's `-device virtio-gpu-gl-pci`

Comment: Ok, when I enable this and add -display gtk,gl=on it does startup and says 3d enabled in dmesg. However, the window is black and stays that way when otherwise weston would show a gui. If I use -display sdl,gl=on instead it aborts with qemu-system-aarch64:Couldn't find current GLX or EGL context.

Comment: WL_SHM_FORMAT_XRGB8888 not available